# Specify redirect_uri when using Facebook login plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

Originally, I authenticated using Facebook using the following code:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http://anotherurl.com/example&scope=public_profile,email
```

I am now trying to do the same thing, but with the Facebook Login plugin here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button/

Which gives me the following code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10&appId=xxxx';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="2" data-size="large" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="true"
         data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true" data-scope="public_profile,email"></div>
</div>
```

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to specify a redirect_uri.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can't, because there is no _need_ to specify one - this is _client-side_  login, that happens in a popup. If you want to redirect the user elsewhere after they logged in - then do so in your own callback for the onlogin event.

Comment: Feel free to send that as an answer and i'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, there doesn't seem to be a way to specify a redirect_uri.

Because there is no *need* to specify one - this is *client-side* login, that happens in a popup, and the result is dealt with in JavaScript.

> How can I do this?

If you want to redirect the user elsewhere after they logged in - then you can do so in your own callback for the `onlogin` event

Comment: There could be a need for a redirect. A redirect from the server to a safe URL is more secure.